# How to use "or" operator in yup "when" validation

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a schema using the following objects:

```
const initialValues = {
 type: "",
 amount: "",
}

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
 type: Yup.string(),
 amount: Yup.number()
   .when('type', {
   is: 'quick',
   then: Yup.number().max(200)
}).required()
})
```

I would like to validate the amount such that I can have multiple is statements like this:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
 ... //other items in the schema
 amount: Yup.number()
   .when('type', {
   is: 'quick',
   then: Yup.number().max(200),
   is: 'long-term',
   then: Yup.number().max(400),
   is: 'short-term',
   then: Yup.number().max(300)
}).required()

})
```

Something like a switch statement for the validation. Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply custom function to `is`.

According to `yup` manuals,

`is` conditions are strictly compared (===) if you want to use a different form of equality you can provide a function like: `is: (value) => value === true`.

I'm not absolutely sure about this code - I used `yup` rather long time ago.

```
.when('type', 
  {
    is: (value) => {
      if (value === 300) {
        // your logic
      }
      // other conditions
    }
  }   
)
```